# what does the np.array command do?

Tags: numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook

question about the `np.array` command.

let's say the content of caches when you displayed it with the print command is

```
caches = [array([1,2,3]),array([1,2,3]),...,array([1,2,3])]
```

Then I executed following code:

```
train_x = np.array(caches)
```

When I print the content of train_x I have:

```
train_x = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],...,[1,2,3]]
```

Now, the behavior is exactly as I want but do not really understand in dept what the `np.array(caches)` command has done. Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: `understanding in depth` is a vague request.  We don't know what you do or do not already know.  Can we assume you know what a numpy array is? And how it's different from a `list`?  How about `np.array([1,2,3])` or `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`?

Comment: Hello, in your first example you create an array with value [1,2,3] but is it the same as command np.array((1,2,3)) because when I execute this line of code I have exactly the same result. An array of [1,2,3]. In the second example you create an array that consists of arrays. So [1,2] and [3,4] are not the values but the shape of the arrays. However for the second example it is not clear for me why you produce a new array that consist of two array's but in 1 column and 2 rows. I expected to have a new array consists of 1 row and 2 columns?

Comment: Sounds like you need a basic understanding, not an in depth one.  Start with basic Python - lists, lists of lists, tuples, postional and keyword arguments.  Then the basics of arrays - shape, dtype, number of dimensions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Making a 1d array

```
In [89]: np.array([1,2,3])
Out[89]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [90]: np.array((1,2,3))
Out[90]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

`[1,2,3]` is a list; `(1,2,3)` is a tuple.  `np.array` treats them as the same.  (`list` versus `tuple` does make a difference when creating structured arrays, but that's a more advanced topic.)

Note the shape is (3,)  (`shape` is a `tuple`)

Making a 2d array from a nested list - a list of lists:

```
In [91]: np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
Out[91]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [92]: _.shape
Out[92]: (2, 2)
```

`np.array` takes data, not `shape` information.  It infers shape from the data.

> array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)

In these examples the `object` parameter is a list or list of lists.  We aren't, at this stage, defining the other parameters.